# Python -- Reading lines from file and split it

Tags: python, arrays, file, split

I'm trying to split the lines from a .txt file stored locally. What I do to make a for loop but I want to start the loop on an specific index on the array. For example:

```
  file_content = open('files/filefinal1_test.txt')
  counter = 0
  total_lines = 0
  global l
  index = 0 if l == "" else file_content.index(l)

  for line in file_content[index:]: 
    l = line
    array_line =line.split('", "')
    array_line[0] = array_line[0].replace('"', '')
    array_line[1] = array_line[1].replace('"', '')
    array_line[2] = array_line[2].replace('"', '')
    array_line[3] = array_line[3].replace('"', '')
    if (send_req(papi, array_line) == 1): 
        counter = counter + 1 
    total_lines = total_lines + 1
```

This gives me errors at : file_content[index:] It's there any way to start the loop at specific line from the file_content?

The fact it's that the code below works and loops the array :

```
for line in file_content: 
        l = line
        array_line =line.split('", "')
        array_line[0] = array_line[0].replace('"', '')
        array_line[1] = array_line[1].replace('"', '')
        array_line[2] = array_line[2].replace('"', '')
        array_line[3] = array_line[3].replace('"', '')
        if (send_req(papi, array_line) == 1): 
            counter = counter + 1 
        total_lines = total_lines + 1
```

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've fount the answer! I didn't call the method .readlines()

```
file_content = file_content.readlines()
for lines in file_content[0:]:
     #stuff
```

Comment: open gives you a file object, readlines gives you a list of the lines in the file: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines

Comment: `for lines in file_content[0:]:` can be written `for lines in file_content:`

Comment: Reusing a variable name to contain different types might not be a good idea in the long run. It's easy to overlook that.

Comment: @Frodon no, file_content it's not an array so it's not the same

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lines = open(filepath, 'rb').readlines()` to get a list of strings, where each string is a line in your file. You can then slice the list at any index you want to only get the lines you are interested in like this: `wanted_lines = lines[index:]` This will get you all the lines from index to the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `islice` from the `itertools` module to create a slice over a file (or any iterable):

```
import itertools
with open('file') as f:
    for line in itertools.islice(f, 3, 5): # 3 and 5 are the start and stop points
        print line
```

see http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice
for more